# Reuse clip-path to clip constant-slope corners from elements of varying aspect-ratios

Tags: svg

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4jxXViyHFnIzwB3AKfGD?p=preview)

1. Clip corners from images
2. Images are of varying aspect ratios
3. If I
   use `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, after scaling the slope will
   vary.
4. **Question:** How to clip different images with the same slope?
   Possible to reuse one `clip-path` definition for all?

Answer (score 1):

You really should have described the details of your problem in the question, not at an external site. I hope I got your question right.

As you want to give the top and bottom of your pictures a slope, how about clipping them one after the other with a very large triangle (works for a max height of the clipped content of 2000):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <polygon points="0,2000 12000,2000 0,0"  />
    </clipPath>  
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 20)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 120)">
      <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 90 120)">
        <rect width="90" height="120" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 90 0)" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <text y="170" font-size="12">90 x 120</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(200 20)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 120)">
      <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 120 120)">
        <rect width="120" height="120" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 120 0)" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <text y="170" font-size="12">120 x 120</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(400 20)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 80)">
      <g clip-path="url(#clip)" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 120 80)">
        <rect width="120" height="80" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 120 0)" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <text y="170" font-size="12">120 x 90</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Ignore the topmost `<g transform>`, that is only for displaying the examples next to each other. The main idea is that you flip the content such that the top-right corner will be clipped off, turn it around to do the same again, and then flip it back to its original position.

For this to work, you need to enter the content width/height in the three transform matrices as shown.

Comment: Thanks.   I made a [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/3zRNuJSX7J8XfeR88u1a?p=preview), which uses your idea of "translate and rotate, then clip, then rotate and translate again".

Answer (score 0):

No need to rotate, actually rotation is not the solution if the clip is not rotationally symmetrical.

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eh24QLXJrUh1QWhB6bTO?p=preview),
in which E is the solution.

Compare C and E,

```
C
<svg ... >
    <g clip-path=...>

        <svg ... >
          <image ... />
        </svg>

    </g>  
</svg>
```

---

```
E
<svg ... >
    <g transform="translate(0 -100)">
    <g clip-path=...>

      <g transform="translate(0 100)">
        <svg ... >
          <image ... />
        </svg>
      </g>

    </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```